# C++ win client send linux server variable

Tags: c++, winsock, send, recv

I'm fairly new to c++ programming. I am trying to code a windows client that communicates to a linux server. That part I have successfully done.

Now I don't know what to do to continue this.
This is what I need to do (but dont know how to).

Now my client asks for 3 stuff.
Example

```
 declared client variables 1,2,3 as string...

 Enter Anything: dgasggfds 
 //dgasggfds is now stored to cvariable1
 Enter Anything again: zxcasd
 //zxcasd is now stored to cvariable2
 Enter Anything again again: qwert
 //qwer is now stored to cvariable3
```

Now the client should send each of this variable to the server.
The server will then also use those variables and execute its codes.

So now on the server

```
 cvariable1 is now svariable1 on the server.
 cvariable2 is now svariable2 on the server.
 cvariable3 is now svariable3 on the server.
```

Once all the variable is there, it will execute a code.

Please advice. Thanks.

--edit--

I tried using send() recv() it works but I can only send 1 variable.
and I dont know how to set the recv data into a variable on the server.

--edit--

I kinda get how to save the recv data into a variable.
But still don't know how to do it with the multiple data.

Also the 3 variables must always be together. they cant be separated.
The servers code needs those 3 variables/data to execute the cmds properly.

--edit--

Does this make any sense?

```
string* packet = new string[3];
packet[0] = 'var1';
packet[1] = 'var2';
packet[2] = 'var3';

//send request
if (send(sock, packet.c_str(), packet.length(), 0) != request.length())
    die_with_wserror("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
```

Its giving me some error though. packet:expression must have class type.

What I'm trying to do now is send it in an array, and break down the array once on the server, is this logic okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On client side concatenate the three variables using a special character to separate them, e.g.

```
string sending = variable1 + "_" + variable2 + "_" + variable3;
```

and send sending

On server side

```
ssize_t bytes_recieved;
char incoming_data_buffer[1000];
bytes_recieved = recv(socketfd, incoming_data_buffer,1000, 0);
```

you will have your data in incoming_data_buffer. Now split incoming_data_buffer using "_", you will have your 3 variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same variables on the server as well. When the client have read and sent the first string, the server stores it in the first variable just like on on the client. And so on for the other two.

Think of it like this: The server receives input from the client, the same way the client receives input from the user. The only difference is that the client uses e.g. `cin` while the server uses `recv`. It can actually be abstracted out into a separate class that handles the input, then you use one instance of that class for `cin` (or rather `istream`) input, while the other get its input from a socket. But the user of this input class uses the same set of functions, no matter where the input comes from.

Comment: I kinda get it but the server code is kinda confusing me because this will be my first c++ on linux. also the server needs all 3 variables then it executes the code. and all the variables from the client will be sent at once, not like user input1 -> send, user input2 -> send. But like this, user input1, input2, input3 -> send. server will recieve the 3 and put each of them to a variable and execute the codes. any ideas?

Comment: @user1553142 Send the variables with a separator (like newline) and on the receiving side split the received string at this separator.